# Simple Inner join suggesting a Include index

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, performance, query-performance

I have this simple inner join query and its execution plan master table has around 34K records and detail table has around 51K records. But this simple query is suggesting me an index with include (containing all master field that I include in select). I wasn't expecting this what could be the reason and remedy.

```
   DECLARE    
    @StartDrInvDate Date ='2017-06-01',
    @EndDrInvDate Date='2017-08-31'

    SELECT
        Mastertbl.DrInvoiceID
       ,Mastertbl.DrInvoiceNo
       ,Mastertbl.DistributorInvNo
       ,PreparedBy
       ,detailtbl.BatchNo
       ,detailtbl.Discount
       ,detailtbl.TradePrice
       ,detailtbl.IssuedUnits
       ,detailtbl.FreeUnits
    FROM scmDrInvoices Mastertbl
    INNER JOIN scmDrInvoiceDetails detailtbl
        ON Mastertbl.DrInvoiceID = detailtbl.DrInvoiceID
    WHERE
    (Mastertbl.DrInvDate BETWEEN @StartDrInvDate AND @EndDrInvDate)
```

[image]

Here is the [link](https://pastebin.com/xv4mBQTJ) for XML plan.

Comment: You sound confused by SQL Server suggesting a better solution than a Clustered Index Scan. What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: I am confused because sql server normally don't recommend such things in such scenarios Moreover record count is small I was expecting atmost index on drinvoicedate date that should work but it is not

Comment: @Zia, also add DDL for the existing tables and indexes to you question. A different clustered index key might be a better solution than the suggested index but it depends on other queries in your workload.

Answer (score 2):

Posting the 'actual' execution plan might help us provide a more complete answer.

As a guess, I'd say that Sql Server probably thinks (based on available statistics) that most rows from scmDrInvoices are going to fall in your `WHERE` date range.  (Out of the 34k rows, how many rows fall between your @StartDrInvDate and @EndDrInvDate?)

The optimizer thinks a clustered index scan of that table (along with a table scan of scmDrInvoiceDetails) and a hash match is the most optimal solution (currently).  It also seems that Sql Server is suggesting you create a 'covering' (*A covering index is one which can satisfy all requested columns in a query without performing a further lookup into the clustered index.*) index on scmDrInvoices, which may still result in an index scan, but the index will probably be much smaller.

You could try running UPDATE STATISTICS on both tables first to see if the optimizer generates a different plan.

Posting the actual execution plan may help us provide a more complete answer.

Comment: My current criteria is returning 1.4K records. Updated the stats but no change in plan. In my post i already included the actual execution plan

Comment: Estimated execution plan is also seems to be same

Comment: You included an 'image' of the execution plan - please post the xml for the execution plan on https://pastebin.com/

Comment: You might be able to get some additional insight by examining various execution plans after adjusting the @EndDrInvDate variable to identify the 'Tipping Point'.  What does the plan look like when using @EndDrInvDate='2017-06-01', then '2017-06-02', then '2017-06-03' and so on until the plan changes significantly.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/xv4mBQTJ is the execution plan in xml

Comment: I have tried same day same suggestion by SQL server, However I am experimenting this

Comment: As I run the query on date range such that all records are returned I get the following warning on first Inner Joiin (Hash Match) Operator used tempdb to spill data during execution with spill level 1

Comment: Do you have an other indexes (other than your primary key) on your 'master' table?  If you don't have any other indexes, Sql Server has no choice but to scan the clustering index - but that should not be a surprise.  If you're going to be searching your master table by DrInvDate (and want to attempt to avoid a clustering index scan), you'll need to create a non-clustered index with the DrInvDate column as the first column of the index.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63846/discussion-between-zia-and-scott-hodgin).